# How to highlight a line in Exel yellow and the cells red when making changes (with more than one change)

Tags: excel, row, cell, highlight

I am using the below formula to highlight a row yellow and the cell red when making a change to a cell. The problem is sometimes we want to make more than one change to a row and want all of the cells that had changes to remain red but this formula wipes out the first red cell when changing the second cell in the row. Is there some exception I can add to prevent that already red cell from changing to yellow when the second change is made?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: The logic you want to program is to highlight yellow *unless it's already yellow*. Test a cell for colour which isn't subject to change.

Comment: No, I want to not highlight a cell yellow if already red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cl      As Long                 ' last used column

    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' change .Row to longest used row number
            ' if your rows aren't of uniform length
            If Sh.Cells(.Row, "A").Interior.Color <> vbYellow And _
               Sh.Cells(.Row, "A").Interior.Color <> vbRed Then
                Cl = Sh.Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(.Row, 1), Sh.Cells(.Row, Cl)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The above procedure isn't tested. In fact, I wonder why you use the Workbook event. However, I did test the function below and perhaps that's all you need.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cl      As Long                 ' last used column

    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' change .Row to longest used row number
            ' if your rows aren't of uniform length
            If Cells(.Row, "A").Interior.Color <> vbYellow And _
               Cells(.Row, "A").Interior.Color <> vbRed Then
                Cl = Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Range(Cells(.Row, 1), Cells(.Row, Cl)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as *Selected* so that others can benefit from your testing effort.

Comment: How do I mark it as selected? Also, one more question maybe you can help. When I copy one cell and paste it to another cell, it highlights the entire row yellow and the cell red & allows for multiple red cells in a line, which I LOVE, but if I copy more than one cell and paste it to another area, it does make the cells red that changed but the rows are not being highlighted yellow. DO you know how I can tweek it? I have tried and failed.

Comment: There is an outlined checkmark at the top left of the answer which you can click to *Select* the answer. Look at the code line `If .CountLarge = 1 Then`. It means when you paste more than one cell the following code won't run. Therefore the red is copied, not applied, and the yellow isn't applied because the code doesn't run. Consider adding an `Else` to the existing `If` and tell the code what to do. You can't just remove the `If` because then all pasted cells would turn red.

Comment: Hi Variatus, can you please write the sub for me? I cannot figure out where to put the Else and what to put.

Comment: I already wrote a sub and you said it worked for you. I think that has changed the conditions. Better put your requirement into a new question.

Comment: Okay, I added a new question.